# Overriding the contact related list

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, related-list

I am a newbie to salesforce.

- I have a requirement where I need to override the **Contact** related list and have to make the columns sortable(ascending and descending) when the user clicks on the column.
- Another requirement is there is a field called **Active__c == true** which is a checkbox. If that active is checked then only those contacts should appear in the related list with all those standard functionalities like new contact button,edit,delete,next,previous links etc.

Whether it can be done. If yes how? Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to create an inline VF page for this, as we can not customize the standard related lists

Comment: Hi Nilesh,Thanks for the reply....How the sorting option can be added to the column..?If you have any example that will be helpful...

Answer (score 3):

**Custom Fiter:**

You need a separate VisualForce page for sure. This [blog](http://salesforcesource.blogspot.in/2008/10/how-to-create-custom-related-list-on.html) explains creating
a new VisualForce page with custom conditions as you wanted. You can add filters in the SOQL while retrieving related entries as below:

```
 Contact con = [Select id, Account.id FROM Contact where Active__c = true Limit 5];
```

**Sorting:**

For sorting, filtering and pagination I have used **DataTables** which does really a good job in manipulating client side tabular data. Refer the example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)

Comment: Hi Karthik,Thanks for the reply....will try this solution and will let you know...